# My screen goes partially black after closing a menu item in Team Fortress 2?

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2

The first time I ran the game it ran nicely, however from the next day I began to see this black box (not the weapon) whenever I open and then close any of the popup windows:

[image: Black box in center of TF2 main menu]

Any window, such as Options, the Shop etc can cause this. The window opens fine, but when I close it it leaves it's box behind. I don't know if it's related, but when I connect to a server and start the game it runs but with tremendous lag.

I'm not using a custom HUD. My PC specs are:

- Intel Pentium g2020 CPU
- 4 GB RAM
- Windows 8.1
- No Dedicated Graphics Card

What can cause this? Is there a fix?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling? Also check that you are using the latest drivers for your graphic card.

Comment: i havent tried reinstalling as it is only two days after my installation. though i think my drivers can be updated.

Comment: If your drivers are up to date, just reinstall.

Comment: The bit at the bottom looks odd. It almost looks as if it's a fake, crudely-edited glitch.

Comment: @Texenox I mean, if you go all paranoid you might think that OP did that with paint but, lets not jump into asumptions lol.

Comment: ok the game is now working fine after updating my hardware!!! thanks to all who helped

Comment: but the memory is getting full after a while. any way to fix that ????

Comment: Have you checked that your computer specs meet the recommended requirements of TF2? Just saying... Also you haven't told us your OS either...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking for techncal support, where their computer does not even meet the bare system requirements to run the game (TF2 has a minimum system requirement of a Direct X 8.1 compliant graphics card, OP does not have any graphic card)

Comment: @Timelord64 That would make a good answer to the question...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue before when opening console windows and closing them their shadow would remain on the screen.

This is generally an issue related to your graphics card. Try setting Team Fortress 2 to it's highest possible setting. I run mine at 1920 x 1080. If this doesn't fix the issue I would recommend updating to the latest driver version and restarting TF2 with the highest resolution.

However, it sounds like you may need a better graphics card in order to run the game properly if you are experiencing severe lag in game.

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution is to upgrade. Your system does not appear to meet the system requirements, and sure enough, it is your graphic card that is below par.

As far as what you report, you have graphical problems.

You report not having a dedicated graphic card, and yet Team Fortress 2 requires "any card compliant with DirectX 8.1".

Ultimately, you might find a solution in updating the driver for your integrated card (the *bare* card your motherboard likely contains, which is responsible for drawing basic image to the screen, ***but is not commonly designed for rendering 3D image***).

Honestly, it is surprising that the menus are the only issue you are having. I have personally observed Team Fortress 2 to be *completely unplayable* with superior dedicated cards.

All this aside, I have also personally played Team Fortress 2 with a well-below par card. While the standard game was unplayable, a friend pointed me in the direction of a modification/hack that scaled the graphics way below the intended level of quality. The characters became blocky, but it worked.

While I no longer have a copy of the modification, and have not got the facility to track it down, I can atest that such a method exists. Perhaps somebody else could address this in an answer, with more information on if it would actually help, and where one could find it.